# RANK only working with reference? Weighted rank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The RANK function does not work when the array to search in is not a reference.
For example

```
RANK(Number,A10:A20)
```

works perfectly, but

```
RANK(Number,{1,2,3})
```

or

```
RANK(Number,A10:A20*10+B10:B20)
```

does not.

Why do the above not work?
How can I get weighted rank of a number without using excess cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `RANK` needs to refer to a cell range (for whatever reason) rather than a calculated or hardcoded array. Not sure why this is the case though. Perhaps someone else knows the answer.

Here's one alternative:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((Number>(A10:A20*10+B10:B20))+0)+1
```

Comment: To simulate RANK function exactly you'd more likely use < or >(depending on whether ranking ascending or descending) but without = and adding 1, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT((Number<(A10:A20*10+B10:B20))+0)+1`

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks, I updated answer. Do you know why `RANK` behaves this way? I noticed this also that it must refer to a cell range rather than any calculated or hardcoded array.

Comment: Don't know why. RANK is one of several functions that only accept ranges, e.g. COUNTIF and all of the "IFS" functions, COUNTBLANK, OFFSET (first argument)

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help here, but just for interest RANK function will accept a "union" as 2nd argument, e.g. `=RANK(A1,(A1:A10,C1:C10))`, allowing ranking against a "discontiguous range"